# How to get selected string in google docs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I tried to use `window.getSelection().toString()`, but it doesn't seem to work. The result is an empty string!
What should I use to get the stuff within the document?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Some context might help duplicate your error.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that this was a google extension issue and not a google docs issue. Which is why you should include more details in your question. Not that I'll help you at this point, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is clear. I don't know what to add.